# Why does parseFloat return an integer on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
parseFloat($(this).css('left')
```

This returns an integer on mobile browsers and a float on the Desktop. Why? It occurs even if I set the browser window to be the exact dimensions of the mobile device under test. jQuery version is 1.8.3. I'm using Chrome Canary on the desktop and Webkit on android / iPhone devices.

If the issue isn't parseFloat() why would `$(this).css('left')` return integers instead of floats on mobile devices?

Comment: What resolutions are you checking with? Can you put together a jsFiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209761/do-mobile-webkit-browsers-have-a-rounding-issue-in-js

Comment: What float does it return?

Comment: Could you make a fiddle for testing? Also how is that a problem? JS has a type `Number` and not int/float types AFAIK, it shouldn't really matter for most use cases.

Comment: (a) AFAIK, `.css('left')` will always return an integer because it works in units of pixels and there's no such thing as a part-pixel. (b) All javascript Numbers are float, consequently calculated values that should be int can sometimes be a very close float value due to limitations of calculation precision. (c) Use `parseInt()`

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot there are no part-pixels? One could set (or as result of JS animation calcs) a left property to a fraction of pixel and it'd be computed even though not having much of a visual effect. You're correct about all JS numbers being IEEE 754 double precision floating point with round-to-nearest-even behavior.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté the fiddle is in the SO question mentioned above

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, the rendered result must be in whole pixels because that's the limit of display precision. The internal, numeric representation of positions/lengths may differ from browser to browser. They *should* round to the same integer value used for display but it would appear, from the question, that they don't all behave the same, and/or they don't externalize their internal values accurately.

Comment: I see, my bad. Just made a fiddle on chrome for android and .css returns an <integer>px http://jsbin.com/oqituj/1/edit

Comment: My earlier comment was based on firebug which often displays part-pixels on style inspector. `.css` will return an integer value in px as Beetroot said, so the issue must be with different parseFloat implementations. As both parseInt and parseFloat will return the same type of number, I believe the only difference would be the number parsing rules.

Comment: *Removed* Ignore me. What I just posted was rubbish. My bad this time.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I didn't get to see it, never mind that. Back on topic, seems like @ Wolf nailed the issue. PC Firefox stores decimal px (returns 2.1px on fiddle above) while Chrome for mobile doesn't (returns 2px). Weirdly enough, PC Chrome returns yet another value (2.1000001... on Chrome Canary, 2.099999... on current stable).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, from your analysis I wonder if `Math.round(parseFloat($(this).css('left')))` correctly reflects the rendered pixel count?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I believe so. `parseInt` will fail in my Chrome stable as it will stop parsing when it encounters the `.` token. `Math.round(parseFloat([...]))` seems to be the most sturdy solution. But I wonder though, if (on Chrome stable) an element is set to `1.9px`, Math.round will return 2px but does 1.9px render as 1px or 2px? Eh I guess we're over-thinking about a maximum of 1px difference. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, agreed. Let's start losing sleep over 1px the day it really matters.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with mobile browsers only. This is same for `PC` also. `Firefox` handle these properties (top, left etc) `with decimals in pixels`. But while rendering Firefox set this to integer values.

But in `Chrome`, they keep the values without decimal places(as integer) and render as it is.

I am not sure of the other browsers which supports decimal places in pixel data. But haven't noticed any other browsers like Firefox which support decimal places.